# what is wrong with first query?it give 1064 error but second query and third works

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

> this is my courses table :
>   student_id || course_id || group
>   12345      || 1         || 0
>   12346      || 2         || 0
>   12347      || 2         || 1

```
//for example $course_id = 2 and $group = 0   
$query=$this->db->query("DELETE FROM courses WHERE group=".$group." AND course_id = ".$course_id);  
$query=$this->db->query("DELETE FROM courses WHERE course_id = ".$course_id);  
$query=$this->db->query("DELETE FROM courses WHERE group=".$group);
```

Comment: add question with proper details as you have said in title third works but in comments you have said ahhh its not working ,so add proper question bcz wrong information can misguide other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group` is [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html) in mysql it is used in backtick

```
$query=$this->db->query("DELETE FROM courses WHERE `group`=".$group." AND course_id = ".$course_id);
```

Or using Active record you can write your query

```
$this->db->where('`group`',$group);
$this->db->where('course_id',$course_id);
$this->db->delete('courses');
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense but why it is working third query though?

Comment: I think it is not working with third query also!!!

Comment: thank u very much u r right third not works i tried and its work u make me happy

Comment: @DishaV. as i said it is not  working third query also its right as OP say in his comment!!